# Row with constant length in SQL Server - is it somehow benefitial

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm designing table that will server as snapshot of data that rarely changes to address performance issues... Anyway, it has to be as fast as it gets. Some time ago I used to do similar thing with MySQL and in that database engine it was beneficial in terms of performance to design table with constant row length (no NULL columns + storing strings in nchar). Is it the same with SQL Server ?

Thanks,Pawel

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you are writing your own caching mechanism. Is that correct? If so, there are many excellent caches available, which can be configured in anyway you require for your purposes.

Comment: Yes, it is. Currently one of the pages invokes query that makes mega-join (it's called avg 200 times per hour). As most of columns have constant values I'm going to aggregate result of that query in one table. Then every some reasonable period of time (let's say: every 2minutes) I'll update it's content with new rows that appear in the systems other tables and remove rows that are deprecated. Updating is not the issue. When it comes to technology, I'm using .NET Framework (ASP .NET)

Comment: Ah, I understand. You're caching *within* SQL server. Please ignore my comment as it doesn't really apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you use the myisam table format?

if so, the records are really the same length (and retrieving a record is simple for the database: headersize + (recordsize * recordnumber) - > really dammned fast (of course, after reading the index ...)

afaik the mssql server uses a "paged" storage format - if so, you will gain no performance boost.

Comment: Hi, I don't remember which table format was used. It was ages ago when I used to play with PHP + MySQL. Thanks for reply